# Robot Framework, How to download a file returned in a response body using only request api

Tags: download, request, robotframework, response-headers

I'm using robot framework to send requests without opening a browser. One of the requests is supposed to download a file. But when I send this request the file is not downloaded (even if I have a 200 status code).

```
${uri}    set variable    /api/pricing/ExportImportParams/downloadExportParams
Create Session    test    ${url}    cookies=&{cookies}
${resp}=    Get Request    test    ${uri}    headers=&{headers}
${resp_code} =    Set Variable    ${resp.status_code}
${resp_code} =    Convert To String    ${resp_code}
Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    Should be Equal    ${resp_code}    200
```

The test is passed while the status code is 200.
But no file is downloaded

Here is the response Headers

> content-disposition: attachment;
>   filename="Export Site Parameter_2020-01-03_09-21-39.xlsx";
>   filename*=UTF-8''Export%20Site%20Parameter_2020-01-03_09-21-39.xlsx 
>   content-length: 3767  content-type:
>   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet 
>   date: Fri, 03 Jan 2020 09:21:38 GMT  server: Kestrel  x-powered-by:
>   ASP.NET

Thanks for helping

Comment: What does it mean the file is not downloaded? Its content is supposedly in the payload of the response.

Comment: an excel file is supposed to be downloaded when this request is sent.
but using robot framework no file is downloaded

Comment: Have you checked the response payload

Comment: Yes the response payload is encrypted, something like 200 characters that doesn't make any sens

Answer (score 2):

Making an assumption that you are using the `RequestsLibrary` to perform the HTTP Get request to retrieve the file. Althought the documentation does not specify it, the `content` attribute of the returned response object contains the data. This can then be easily stored in a file using the standard `OperatingSystem` library.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    RequestsLibrary
Library    OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
File Download Using RequestsLibrary


    ${file_name}      Set Variable    file_example_XLS_10.xls
    ${uri}            Set Variable    /wp-content/uploads/2017/02/${file_name}

    Create Session    test    https://file-examples.com
    ${response}=          Get Request    test    ${uri}

    Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    Should Be Equal As Numbers     ${response.status_code}    200

    Create Binary File     ${EXECDIR}/${file_name}     ${response.content}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm using requestLibrary. With your proposition, I'm obtaining an error 404.

Comment: Can you replace the URL with something you know you can reach? The script works for me (different location/network, same machine).